# How to add php in views?

Tags: views

I created a view, and I need to put some PHP or JavaScript in it. I would like to add some if conditions.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. The answer to your question is _yes_, although that doesn't help you much. May you expand your question, and explain what you need to achieve? That would make the answer more detailed, and useful to you (and future readers).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

If you want to use PHP in views header, you can go to configure header, select "Global: Text area" and have to change text format to PHP code; you have to first install the PHP filter module.

If you want to use PHP in view fields, you can use the [Computed field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module.

If you want to use PHP in a view itself, [you have to customize your views](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/drupal-6-views-templates-544.html) and then you can easily add PHP code to it.

Answer (score 3):

It kind a depends of where in your view you want to use php. But if it is in fields there are two options:

1. [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) (d6 only)
2. [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) - in dev though

Answer (score 0):

in the field of view  you can add Global PHP field 
you can fiend this field in the header or in footer